# Get the time the users in their timezone submitted

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Our application uses **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** to store an event when a user submitted the data. This is stored in a **TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE** type column. Our servers are in PST timezone, but I want to see what time one of our users in Australia submitted the data in Australian time? I am confused how to do this properly? When I query the database right now this column seems to show the date the row was submitted but in PST time for every row.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
datetime_submitted -- I want this to display the time this value was created in Australian time not PST
FROM my_table
WHERE user = 'AUSTRALIAN';
```

Comment: I take it you want to display the timestamp in a different timezone depending on the user. Do you have that user/timezone relationship available somewhere in that same table, or perhaps in a user table?

Comment: Yes, I am on the west coast in the US where our servers are. One of our users is in Australia and they submitted some data. I want to know see what time it was on their local personalized computer when they made the submission. I do not have a relationship, but in the same row it says which Country the request came from.

Comment: That won't be enough. Countries can have multiple different timezones (Australia being one of them). How will you know which timezone to pick?

Comment: The users are in specific buildings in our company. We know the location of where they are exactly. But very good point!

Comment: Shouldn't CURRENT_TIMESTAMP also store the timezone? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions037.htm

Comment: Yes but as you mentioned it is stored as a **TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE** so it will not remember that timezone. Instead it will convert it to the server timezone and then serve it back in the local time later. So you just need to change your session timezone to the one that you want to see it as.

Comment: Okay. So with ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='+9:30'; I can do this, but this will convert all the times, I only want to convert that columns data, there are other date fields which I do not want to convert, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the AT TIME ZONE clause:

```
select systimestamp                                 as server_timestamp, 
       systimestamp at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' as australia_timestamp 
from   dual;

SERVER_TIMESTAMP                       AUSTRALIA_TIMESTAMP                  
-------------------------------------- --------------------------------------
12-AUG-16 04.12.23.789000000 PM -05:00 13-AUG-16 07.12.23.789000000 AM AUSTRALIA/SYDNEY
```

Right now it is 4:12:23 PM on 12 August 2016 at my location (Central time, US); it is already tomorrow in Australia, as you can see from the example. (Reminds me the joke - don't worry about the end of the world coming today, it's already tomorrow in Australia!)

Comment: Works! Thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just look at the time in the user's time zone you can set the session to whatever time zone the user is located in then when you select the times it should give it back to you in that time zone as if you were that user.

```
% setenv ORA_SDTZ '+09:30'
```

or

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='+9:30';
```

Reference for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG263

**Updated**

If you only want one column displayed in a different time zone then you can convert it.

To convert the timezone just in the query you can just use `CAST(date_field AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern' AS time_name` on the column you want to change.

Reference for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699

Comment: The database design was already created years ago and it was created with this datatype of column. I am unable to change it now.

Comment: @user2924127 You should just need to change your timezone to where ever your users are. (This essentially allows you to "act" like you were in that timezone) Let me know if this works as you would like. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This will change all the dates, is it possible to only convert that one columns date?

Comment: @user2924127 Are you trying to convert it in the database or just query it? I'm not sure if you can only do it for one column. It may be easier if you pull your data and just convert it locally (i.e. in excel).

Comment: @user2924127 If you want to just change it for one column in the query use `AT TIME ZONE '+9:30'`

Answer (score 0):

First, your application need to receive exact date time with user local timezone. For example, if you have typical web application with frontend, backend and database, then your frontend need to send exact date time with local user timezone (for example "2016-08-08 03:00:00CST") to your backend. Backend need to save this in a table as-is keeping date, time, timezone information received from frontend. Oracle needs to store date, time and timezone into database as-is so `datetime_submitted` column should have information about time zone. Suitable data type for it will be `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CDEGDFFE

Comment: Reading this makes sense, but this is an older database with already a lot of data, we can't change it now. This is currently how the database has been storing so is it possible to do what we need to do?

Comment: Per datatype description, value is stored in database time zone, so column values itself don't have information about local user time zone. As a permament solution, I'd suggested migration to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`  but this wouldn't help with existing data. Look for other clues in user's data - probably you have info which would help to guess their timezone, for example address or state or something similar. There is a separate simple case when user itself views her own data - then you can just convert dates to their local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not fully understand data type `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`. Data type `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` shows time values **always and only** in current user session time zone.

When you work with time zones then often you get an advise like: "Store **all** times in UTC time and convert displayed value at application layer." That is exactly how `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` works. The mayor difference is, times are not stored at `UTC` but at `DBTIMEZONE` (unless you set DBTIMEZONE = UTC, of course). Hence you cannot modify `DBTIMEZONE` setting once you have any data in a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column.

You get an error if you try for example `TO_CHAR(datetime_submitted, 'hh24:mi:ss TZR')`, because time zone region is by definition always your current user session time zone.

The database does not know the time zone of your users in Australia, because all stored times where converted to PST time zone (well, most likely to `-08:00` but skip the details here).

If you like to see the values in a different time zone then you have to change your current user session time zone. Typically you do this by `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE=...` or by environment variable, resp. Registry setting `ORA_SDTZ`.

Another solution is to cast to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.